# 2D Bin Packing / Tile Algorithm - Rectanglar Tiles inside a Polygon

Tags: algorithm, polygon, tile, bin-packing

I'm working on a problem.  I want to efficiently tile a polygon.

- The polygon is random. It could be literally any shape from a triangle (# of sides = 3) to a circle (# of sides = infinity).  It could be concave or convex.
- All tiles are fixed size rectangles.
- All tiles will have the same orientation.
- If it makes the conversation easier, we can use squares as the tile shape.
- Tiles are oriented parallel/perpendicular to the longest leg of the polygon, where ever that is.
- I'm running in JavaScript on the browser, and I'm only using one polygon.  In fact, the polygon is generated manually by a user.
- I don't need crazy high packing efficiency, but reasonable performance to tile the polygon. (I'm not looking for an NP-hard solution here..)
- I will only be filling one polygon, and I doubt the tile count would ever exceed 100.

I've found an excellent reference to test polygon to polygon interference.  Code gleamed from [this posting,](http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/randomtile/) written by Paul Bourke.

The general intersection test between two polygons is as follows:

```
/*
   Return FALSE if two polygon intersect.
   Polygon p1[] is of length n1 and polygon p2[] is of length n2.
   Polygons are define with vertices ordered clockwise.
*/
int PolygonPolygon(XY *p1,XY *p2,int n1,int n2)
{
   int i,j;
   // Reject if a vertex of p1 is inside p2, And visa versa
   for (i=0;i<n2;i++) {
      if (InsidePolygon(p1,n1,p2[i]))
         return(FALSE);
   }
   for (i=0;i<n1;i++) {
      if (InsidePolygon(p2,n2,p1[i]))
         return(FALSE);
   }
   // Reject any intersecting edges
   for (j=0;j<n1;j++) {
      for (i=0;i<n2;i++) {
         if (LineIntersect(p1[j].x,p1[j].y,p1[(j+1)%n1].x,p1[(j+1)%n1].y,
                           p2[i].x,p2[i].y,p2[(i+1)%n2].x,p2[(i+1)%n2].y))
            return(FALSE);
      }
   }
   return(TRUE);
}
```

The supporting functions for these tests are given here: [LineIntersect.c](http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/randomtile/LineIntersect.c) and here: [InsidePolygon.c](http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/randomtile/InsidePolygon.c).  (Update:  Obviously I will have to modify these three functions a bit to look if the tile is either fully OUTSIDE of the polygon or with intersecting a polygon edge.  Apologies for leaving that out initially...  It goes without saying I have to convert them to JavaScript as well.)

My questions here relate to a reasonable algorithm to do the tiling.

Method 1 (the blind leading the blind)

- go to upper left hand corner of the polygon's outer bounds.  Grid layout with the tiles until the all bounds are covered with a tile. Test for interference, or out of bounds.
- if interference, remove the tile.
- I do have to modify the intersection test for this method to include the test "Are all four vertices of the tile located outside of the polygon?"  If so, delete that tile.

Method 2 (slide it till it stops)

- Select a point at center of mass to the bounds of the polygon.
- Center a tile there.  Test for interference.
- If interference, grab another random point XYZ distance away from center of mass, try again. Attempt X more times at different orientations, if fail, increase radius y more times and try again. If totally no go, sigh, and prompt the user to click the mouse in the largest open area within the polygon.
- From that point, slide towards the center of longest leg of the polygon, the one that sets the tile's angular orientation.  Increment, test, increment test.  At some point the tile will hit something. Slide the tile to "*bottom left" it hits something else.  Stop. From there tile the rest of the polygon till you hit the bounds.  Delete all tiles that are outside of polygon or interfere with the polygon's boundary.

My gut says method 2 will generate better results, but then there's this use case:  [image: tile into polygon]

I've done a lot of reviews on bin packing, but because the polygon shape is so odd, they don't really seem to fit. Here's a great reference, [Solving the 2D Packing Problem by Rod Stephens](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/36005) There is a whole lot of stuff on tile / packing a rectangle, not much at all on packing a polygon.

Is there a better algorithm?  Are there holes in either of my two algorithms? Anybody been here before?  Many thanks.

Edit: I received a comment asking for an image showing a desired output.  As I was preparing a solution I realized a few errors in my original stated question (involving the interference tests required).  I've added a desired output image with labeled tiles to ease whatever conversation is coming next. I also realize I should probably add a third method.

Method #3, One strip at a time.  Slide and check.

- start at left hand side of longest leg of the polygon.  Add a tile, see if it fits, if interference, slide it "right" until there is no interference.
- Add more tiles to finish the row.
- Start the next row immediately above the start row.  Push the tile as far "left" as it will go.
- Add more tiles to finish the row.
- Continue to add rows, slide left, then slide right.
- There was a real trick on the top row of the example shown. The surprise was tiles #11 and #12    I think that adds a modification that is... when the end of the row hits, you should continue an incremental slide and retest until you reach the outer bounds of the polygon.

A proposed completed solution:

[image: square tiles contained within a polygon]

Note: I don't have an method that would work to identify tile #13 unless it just fit in method one using blind luck.

Comment: Could you add a version of the image with the tiling you'd want to achieve, just for clarity?

Comment: I think I understand. Yes. I see that the code provided needs a logical test change, and that could be confusing.  I will amend the problem statement.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @m69  Is this better?  I do have to thank you.. while doing that drill I realized a few opportunities for improvements... thx.

Comment: With this kind of geometrical question, I find it's always best to include an image of the desired result. A picture tells a thousand words, and people will grasp what your question is about much more quickly.